# How to get a specific part of page into a window form in c#?

Tags: c#, css, winforms, webbrowser-control, edit

I'm trying to get a specific part of a web application written in aspx and place it on my windows form programm..particularly there is an application here http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/ktbasemap/default.aspx and i want to create an executable windows form application, without the right frame and the images above...i cant download the aspx cause it doesnt work, the only thing is by editing the css..But can i edit the css of a website through c# code dynamically??Any ideas making that program??